# Iframe Cookies Blocked IE - Alternative way

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe

Example Iframe: http://goo.gl/25ecS
index.php

```
<?php
   header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>EXAMPLE</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="foob"   width="100%" height="550" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="yes" onLoad="window.parent.scroll(0,0);"   src="http://www.xxxxx.com/buildyourown/Results/Results_xsl.aspx?aff=&incdirect=1&boardType=&rooms=1&rating=2&r3c_ages=2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2&r1a=2&r2c=0&r2i_ages=0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0&r3i=0&airportto=LCA&r1i=0&r1c=0&r1i_ages=0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0&_stage=search&locationset=&populardestinations=3100&r2a=2&r2c_ages=2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2&r3c=0&locationto=3100&aclocationto=&flexibility=3&r1c_ages=2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2&r3a=2&r3i_ages=0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0&airportfrom=LON&airportfromfreetext=&r2i=0&spechotelname=&freetext=-+type+your+destination+-&numadults=2&numchildren=0&numinfants=0&_searchrandom=711211764-20399-68269&search_type=Flight_Hotel_Transfer&startdate_d=19&startdate_m=4&startdate_y=2013&enddate_d=26&enddate_m=4&enddate_y=2013&startdate=10+June+2013&enddate=17+June+2013&transport=transfer" /></iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

Iframe is working ff or chrome but internet expolerer blocked cookies. i dont know how to fix this problem. I put this code (  header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"'); ) on the top my page but still doesnt work. when i click to basket shopping, there is havent any basket.

Comment: Do you have this set in the iframe URL or just the parent?

Comment: Also, do you have control over the IE browser (for example, is this installed in a corporate environment)? If not, the user can opt-out of 3rd party cookies. Therefore, passing that header will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here are three suggestions (not necessarily solution) that may help:

- **SESSION variables:** If you are trying to store information only for that session, consider using a session variable.
- **Browser storage:** Second suggestion is to consider storing information in the browser ([jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/)) which works on both mobile and desktop in some of the more modern browsers including Internet Explorer 6+.  I believe both should work with iframes.
- **Pop-ups:** Consider using a pop-up, form or other mechanism to 'break-out' of the iframe. A number of 3rd party shopping carts are implemented as pop-ups to get around these sort of restrictions.